# Can you use an image as the background of a HTML slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use a grey scale image as the background, so that the user is able to input a greyscale intensity by modifying the slider. but I'm not sure whether it is possible or how to do it.  Thank you.

Something kind of like this:
[image]

Comment: Of course, that's possible with canvas. Otherwise, you'll need to animate in the new images dependent on sliding.

Comment: Could you also provide a sample code?

Comment: It would take me more than 15 minutes to write and test it. I have my own projects. Stack Overflow is not a site where we do your work for you, but rather help you and fix what you've done wrong or don't understand. Please show us effort. We actually need your sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style thumbs and tracks, but it is different CSS for pretty much all browsers. See https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/ for the details.

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black, white);
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vms19x32/

Comment: Thank you for your help!